# XSLT Concatenation with Different Attributes

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

My input XML looks like this:

```
<data>
    <Food_Output FoodNbr="171179">
        <Parent>
            <row outputname="Menu Price 200.0" outputvalue="3" costvalue="0" outputid="26" send_to_kitchen="1" adjusted="0" id_server="42" />
            <row outputname="Menu Price 212.0" outputvalue="5" costvalue="0" outputid="26" send_to_kitchen="1" adjusted="0" id_server="42" />
        </Parent>
    </Food_Output>
    <Food_Input FoodNbr="171179">
        <Parent>
            <row id_price="212.2" text_cmnt1="Approved" text_cmnt2="Regular Menu Item"/>
            <row id_price="200.0" text_cmnt1="Declined" text_cmnt2="Regular Menu Item"/>
        </Parent>
    </Food_Input>
</data>
```

And I'd like my output XML to look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<addtn_kitchen_data>
   <test>Menu Price 200.0</test>
   <tblGuests>
      <desc_adjmt_type>Regular Menu Item 212.2</desc_adjmt_type>
      <text_credit_apprl>Approved</text_credit_apprl>
      <text_cmnts>Regular Menu Item</text_cmnts>
      <nbr_adjmt>5</nbr_adjmt>
   </tblGuests>
   <tblGuests>
      <desc_adjmt_type>Regular Menu Item 200.0</desc_adjmt_type>
      <text_credit_apprl>Declined</text_credit_apprl>
      <text_cmnts>Regular Menu Item</text_cmnts>
      <nbr_adjmt>3</nbr_adjmt>
   </tblGuests>
</addtn_kitchen_data>
```

This is the XSLT that I'm applying to it to try and get to that output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" 
    exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <addtn_kitchen_data>
            <test>
                <xsl:value-of select="data/Food_Output/Parent/row[@id_server='42']/@outputname"/>
            </test>
            <xsl:for-each select="data/Food_Input/Parent/row">
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="@id_price">
                            <tblGuests>
                                <desc_adjmt_type><xsl:value-of select="@text_cmnt2"/><xsl:text> </xsl:text> <xsl:value-of select="@id_price"/>
                                </desc_adjmt_type>
                                <text_credit_apprl><xsl:value-of select="@text_cmnt1"/></text_credit_apprl>
                                <text_cmnts><xsl:value-of select="@text_cmnt2"/></text_cmnts>
                                <nbr_adjmt>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="/data/Food_Output/Parent/row[@outputname='Menu Price 200.0']/@outputvalue"/>
                                </nbr_adjmt>
                            </tblGuests>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </addtn_kitchen_data>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Right now I'm hardcoding the @outputname in the XSLT to equal 'Menu Price 200.0'. Essentially, I'm looking for an XPath query that matches the value within the @outputname (200.0 in my example) to the corresponding @id_price (200.0) if and only if the string within the @outputname contains 'Menu Price'.

Something along the lines of this (this is not correct):

```
<xsl:value-of select="/data/Quote_Output/Parent/row[@outputname='Menu Price" & @id_grd & "']/@outputvalue"/>
```

Can anyone suggest an XPath that would get me what I need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *could* do it this way:

```
<nbr_adjmt>
    <xsl:value-of select="/data/Food_Output/Parent/row[@outputname=concat('Menu Price ', current()/@id_price)]/@outputvalue"/>
</nbr_adjmt>
```

A better way might be to define a [**key**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#key):

```
<xsl:key name="row-by-price" match="row" use="substring-after(@outputname, 'Menu Price ')" />
```

then use it as:

```
<nbr_adjmt>
    <xsl:value-of select="key('row-by-price', @id_price)/@outputvalue"/>
</nbr_adjmt>
```

Comment: Thanks @michael.hor257k. That gets me super close. Yet I'm still missing the outputvalue attribute value from the second child row element of FoodOutput/Parent. That value should be "5". My output here: http://xsltransform.net/eiZQaG5.

Comment: That is because "212.0" does not match "212.2". Compare:  http://xsltransform.net/eiZQaG5/1

Comment: Super. Just a small change makes a big difference. Thanks again @michael.hor257k. Again you've helped me greatly.